# POSTGRESQL : SET CONSTRAINTS all DEFERRED; Does not work for FK constraints

Tags: postgresql, insert, foreign-keys, constraints

I have an issue with INSERT procedure and i get error: "table "lab" violates foreign key constraint "fk_lab_act"".

```
"SET CONSTRAINTS all DEFERRED"
```

has no effect, and if i try SET CONSTRAINTS "fk_lab_act" DEFERRED - i got a message that there is no such constraint.

my code:

```
 create or replace procedure "DB_ESG".insert_lab()
    language plpgsql
    as $$
    begin
    SET CONSTRAINTS all DEFERRED;
    insert into "DB_ESG".lab select * from public.data_lab on conflict do nothing;
    commit;end;$$;
```

The error:

SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: insert or update on table "lab" violates foreign key constraint "fk_lab_act"
Key (Act_number)=(00001-ТР-230822-В-1) is not present in table "acts".
PL/pgSQL function "DB_ESG".insert_lab() line 5 at COMMIT

When i create table i create FK as named constraint, but anyway Postgres tells me that there is no such constraint.

like:

```
 CREATE TABLE lab(
   ID int not null,
    Act_number text,
    constraint "fk_lab_act"
    foreign key("Act_number") references "DB_ESG".ACTS("ACT_NUM") ON DELETE cascade deferrable        initially deferred);
```

Tried "SET session_replication_role = replica;" but i have no permission.

When i try to disable triggers all, i also have the error:
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_18672" is a system trigger

PostgreSQL v15.2

Comment: 1) What does `show search_path;` return? 2) What happens if you do `SET CONSTRAINTS "DB_ESG"."fk_lab_act" DEFERRED`  **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-set-constraints.html) *DEFERRED constraints are not checked until transaction commit*. However your code has that `commit` immediately following the insert. It is on the `commit` the error is occurring; exactly where you told it to.  If you processing after the procedure, remove the commit back to the calling procedure/process.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver search_path shows (public,public,"$user"). With i add schema name "DB_ESG"."fk_lab_act" - i have no warnigs that constraint does not existst.

Comment: 1) This `public,public,"$user"` can be simplified to `public,"$user"`. 2) Read [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html). 3) Either add `"DB_ESG"` to the `search_path` or always schema qualify `"fk_lab_act` as `"DB_ESG"."fk_lab_act"`. You can persist `search_path` in `postgresql.conf` per [Client connection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html)